# Rewrite MS SQL query for MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

A while back a user posted an interesting query that was written for MS SQL and it relies on common table expressions (CTE). Can anyone offer any direction on what this query would look like for MySQL?

I'm including the entire sample which also creates a temporary table with some sample data. I'm just interested in the appointment query for MySQL. Below the query I'm posting the expected output.

Here is a link to the original post:
[HALF-an-hour and One-hour time slot booking based on selection- c# and sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31835935/half-an-hour-and-one-hour-time-slot-booking-based-on-selection-c-sharp-and-sql)

```sql
-- Sample data from the question.
declare @Appointment table
(
    [ID] bigint not null identity(1, 1), -- Primary key.
    [BookedDate] date not null,          -- The date of the appointment.
    [Time] time(0) not null,             -- The start time of the appointment.
    [Duration] int not null              -- The length of the appointment in minutes.
);
insert @Appointment
    ([BookedDate], [Time], [Duration])
values
    ('2014-04-15', '09:00', 60),
    ('2014-04-15', '10:00', 30),
    ('2014-04-15', '17:00', 60),
    ('2014-04-15', '18:30', 30);

-- @StartTime is the time the office opens on the desired date.
-- @EndTime is the time the office closes on the desired date.
-- @Interval is the number of minutes that separate potential appointment times.
-- @DesiredDate is the date on which an appointment is requested.
-- @DesiredLength is the length of the requested appointment in minutes.
declare @StartTime time(0) = '09:00';
declare @EndTime time(0) = '21:00';
declare @Interval int = 30;
declare @DesiredDate date = '2014-04-15';
declare @DesiredLength int = 30;

-- This CTE enumerates all potential timeslots on the @DesiredDate given the above data.
with [TimeSlotCTE] as
(
    -- Base case: the first appointment slot of the day.
    select 
        [From] = @StartTime, 
        [To] = dateadd(minute, @DesiredLength, @StartTime)

    union all

    -- Recursive case: create a subsequent appointment slot as long as doing so won't
    -- take us past the office's closing time.
    select
        dateadd(minute, @Interval, [From]),
        dateadd(minute, @Interval, [To])
    from
        [TimeSlotCTE]
    where
        dateadd(minute, @Interval, [To]) <= @EndTime
)

-- Finally, we simply select every time slot defined above for which there does not
-- yet exist an overlapping appointment on the requested date.
select
    [T].[From],
    [T].[To],
    [Available] = 
        case when exists 
        (
            select 1 from @Appointment [A]
            where
                -- Forgot this line the first time around!
                [A].[BookedDate] = @DesiredDate and
                [A].[Time] < [T].[To] and
                dateadd(minute, [A].[Duration], [A].[Time]) > [T].[From]
        )
        then 'No' else 'Yes' end
from
    [TimeSlotCTE] [T];
```

Output

```
From        To          Available
09:00:00    09:30:00    No
09:30:00    10:00:00    No
10:00:00    10:30:00    No
10:30:00    11:00:00    Yes
11:00:00    11:30:00    Yes
11:30:00    12:00:00    Yes
12:00:00    12:30:00    Yes
12:30:00    13:00:00    Yes
13:00:00    13:30:00    Yes
13:30:00    14:00:00    Yes
14:00:00    14:30:00    Yes
14:30:00    15:00:00    Yes
15:00:00    15:30:00    Yes
15:30:00    16:00:00    Yes
16:00:00    16:30:00    Yes
16:30:00    17:00:00    Yes
17:00:00    17:30:00    No
17:30:00    18:00:00    No
18:00:00    18:30:00    Yes
18:30:00    19:00:00    No
19:00:00    19:30:00    Yes
19:30:00    20:00:00    Yes
20:00:00    20:30:00    Yes
20:30:00    21:00:00    Yes
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment.

You can move to MySQL 8+ for a direct conversion.  MySQL now supports common table expressions (CTEs) and recursive CTEs.  The code would, of course, change for MySQL conventions, but overall it would be the same.

An alternative is to use a `numbers` table in both databases to construct the appointment starts.  This might be a good idea from the performance perspective.