# Convert SQL Server / C# Query to PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new to postgres, I was facing an issue but I found the solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31841098/15663795

But the issue is this query is not in PostgreSQL. Can Someone help in converting this query?

```
with [TimeSlotCTE] as
(
    -- Base case: the first appointment slot of the day.
    select 
        [From] = @StartTime, 
        [To] = dateadd(minute, @DesiredLength, @StartTime)

    union all

    -- Recursive case: create a subsequent appointment slot as long as doing so won't
    -- take us past the office's closing time.
    select
        dateadd(minute, @Interval, [From]),
        dateadd(minute, @Interval, [To])
    from
        [TimeSlotCTE]
    where
        dateadd(minute, @Interval, [To]) <= @EndTime
)
```

I tried this:

```
WITH TIMESLOTS AS
                (SELECT * FROM (VALUES('09:00','09:30')) BASE("start","end")
                    UNION ALL SELECT "start" + interval '30 minutes',
                        "end" + interval '30 minutes')
SELECT *
FROM TIMESLOTS;
```

but it is showing following error
`column "start" does not exist`

Comment: I tried this but it is showing error
```
WITH TIMESLOTS AS
    (SELECT * FROM (VALUES('09:00','09:30')) BASE("start","end");
     UNION ALL SELECT "start" + interval '30 minutes',
      "end" + interval '30 minutes')
SELECT *
FROM TIMESLOTS;
```

Comment: [edit] what you tried into the question. And post any errors (after googling them).

Comment: this is the error I am getting
ERROR:  column "start" does not exist

Comment: recursive cte in PostgreSQL https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-recursive-query/

Comment: `@StartTime` seems to be a parameter passed to the function that contains that SQL Server statement. So you need to create such a parameter in your function as well. What exactly does the original statement do? The assignments inside the SELECT list look strange, but maybe you can replace that with a simple `generate_series()` call.